# Machine Learning: What is the format of video inputs that I can pass for my machine learning algorithm to analyze input video?

Tags: machine-learning

There are certain machine learning algorithms in use that takes videos files as input. If I have to pull all the videos from youtube that are associated with a certain tag and provide them as input to this algorithm, what should be my input format?

Answer (score -1):

There is no format in which you can pass a video to a machine learning algorithm, since it won't understand the contents of the video.

You need to preprocess the video first, which might depend on how you have to use it. In general you can do something like converting each frame of the video to CSV (same as preprocessing an image), which you can pass to your machine learning algorithm. If you want to process your frames sequentially, you may want to use a Recurrent Neural Network. Also if the video has some audio, then just find its audio time series, and combine each part of the time series with its corresponding video frame.